# pure function of functions that returns functions in D

Tags: functional-programming, functor, d, pure-function

I'm trying to create a pure function that returns the multiplication of two other pure functions:

```
pure Func multiplyFunctions(Func,Real)(scope const Func f1, scope const Func f2)
{
    return (Real a) { return f1(a) * f2(a); };
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm running into problems, number one, I want to declare f1 and f2 to be pure functions/delegates/classes with opCall defined... which is required because I'm calling them from a pure function.

But number two, and what seems to be the most problematic, is that I want f1 and f2 to be functions of one, "Real" variable that return one "Real" value... but I can't figure out how to template this out...

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've been trying to clean up the [tag:pure] tag, because it sometimes refers to pure virtual functions, sometimes to [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) and sometimes to [pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_(programming_language)) - among others. But I don't know anything about [tag:d2]. Could you confirm if my tag edit is appropriate? Would [tag:purely-functional] work for this question - I created [tag:pure-function], so if [tag:purely-functional] works I think it would be better to use the existing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, remove the `scope`; it's wrong, because the scopes of the delegates are escaped.

Second, try something like:

```
real delegate(real) multiplier(const real delegate(real) pure f1,
                               const real delegate(real) pure f2) pure
{
    real multiply(real val) { return f1(val) * f2(val); }
    return &multiply;
}
```

You can also try doing this with templates, although there's not much of a reason to:

```
pure auto multiplier(alias F1, alias F2)(ParameterTypeTuple!F1 args)
{
    return F1(args) * F2(args);
}

real square(real a) pure { return a * a; }

alias multiplier!(square, square) squareMultiplier;

//Now squareMultiplier is a multiplier of square()
```

Note that there are **bugs** in the compiler that don't allow purity to be 100% correct, so you'll just have to put up with them for now.

Comment: What if I don't use a delegate, but a function pointer?  or a class with opCall specified?  can these be implicitly changed to delegate?  I like the second version, and will have to look into that, (it could take any set of arguments, as long as they were the same for F1 and F2?).  Also, what do you mean by bugs?  I know you can't cast delegates to const(delegates), and purity has been weakened, are there others?  Thanks!

Comment: one more thing, for the second part, if the functions are not known at compile time, can I still use the alias method?

Comment: @Andrew: You *can't* use a function pointer, because, by definition, function pointers don't have *state* -- i.e. they can't "remember" your two functions. As for a class with `opCall`, if you go in that direction, use the second version; the first version isn't suited for it. :) By bugs, I mean that you'll eventually run into the point where something that should be able to be pure in fact won't be able to (e.g. try declaring the inner function as `pure`...), because they're still working on it. DMD 2.055 should have many improvements, though.
I don't know of others specifically right now.

Comment: @Andrew: In theory, yes; you just say `multiplier!(funcptr1, funcptr2)`. In practice, you'll have to try it and see -- I remember there was a corruption bug once (and there were in general lots of problems with local template instantiations), but they've probably fixed most of them by now.